# URL not typing in firefox selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Url is not tying in firefox browser. I am using latest version of selenium jar(ver:27) and latest version of firefox(40.0.3).

My code is:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class first {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please udate your jar to latest one. Had similar problem with old java jar and latest firefox

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Selenium is 2.47.1. The current version of Firefox is 41.0. If you get them both updated, it should work.

[Selenium download page](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Comment: That's great. If this answer (or any answer) helped you, please accept it.